# python: specify return value of attribute of mocked module

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-mock

I have a module ex which has multiple attributes and another module that uses these attributes like this

```
import ex
def use_ex(attr):
    z = getattr(ex,attr)
    #Do something with z
```

In my test file, I mock the ex as I cannot import it in the test environment.

```
sys.modules['ex'] = Mock()
```

How do I specify the return_value of ex.attr when I write the test for use_ex?

Comment: `sys.modules['ex'].attr.return_value = desired_value`?

Comment: @Goyo doesn't work

Comment: Can you provide more detail? What return value do you need? Your code seems not to call `z`, so there is no chance to provide a `return_value`. You can directly set attributes on Mock objects. `ex = Mock(); ex.x = 3`. There is also `unittest.mock.PropertyMock` if you do just want a plain value.

Comment: Works for me. Maybe you want `sys.modules['ex'].attr = desired_value`? But that is just the value, not the return value.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes this is what is needed to do. Thanks

Comment: @Goyo yes, it was a data attribute not a function so i just needed to set the value

Answer (score -1):

You can specify mock return values like this :

```
return_value = whatyouwant
my_mock = Mock()
my_mock.return_value = return_value
sys.modules['ex'] = my_mock
```

Comment: Actually i just needed to set the attribute value of the mocked module